# How to convert a pandas plot into an image

Tags: python, django, pandas, matplotlib

I am working on an app which will be able to show a graph of the company's performance in stocks, I wanted to turn the pandas plot of that company into an image without saving it. Can someone tell me what to do?

```
from fastquant import get_pse_data
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
    
df = get_pse_data(symbol, '2019-01-01', '2020-01-01')
ma30 = df.close.rolling(30).mean()
close_ma30 = pd.concat([df.close, ma30], axis=1).dropna()
```

I am actually thinking of adding this plot derived from a pandas dataframe `close_ma30 = pd.concat([df.close, ma30], axis=1).dropna()` into my html code:

[image]

I want to create a python function that will allow me to return it as an image for a django code. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use *Dataframe-image* to convert a pandas plot into a image, you can Visit *https://pypi.org/project/dataframe-image/*.
dataframe_image has the ability to export both normal and styled DataFrames as images from within a Python script. Pass your normal or styled DataFrame to the export function along with a file location to save it as an image.

```
>>> import dataframe_image as dfi
>>> dfi.export(df_styled, 'df_styled.png')
```

You may also export directly from the DataFrame or styled DataFrame using the dfi.export and export_png methods, respectively.

```
>>> df.dfi.export('df.png')
>>> df_styled.export_png('df_styled.png)
```

**As a Python Library**
Dataframe_image can also be used outside of the notebook as a normal Python library. In a separate Python script, import the dataframe_image package and pass the file name of your notebook to the convert function.

```
>>> import dataframe_image as dfi
>>> dfi.convert('path/to/your_notebook.ipynb',
                to='pdf',
                use='latex',
                center_df=True,
                max_rows=30,
                max_cols=10,
                execute=False,
                save_notebook=False,
                limit=None,
                document_name=None,
                table_conversion='chrome'
                chrome_path=None,
                latex_command=None,
                output_dir=None,
                )
```

By default, the new file(s) will be saved in the same directory where the notebook resides. Do not run this command within the same notebook that is being converted.

From the Command Line
The command line tool dataframe_image will be available upon installation with the same options as the convert function from above.

```
dataframe_image --to=pdf "my notebook with dataframes.ipynb"
```

Finding Google Chrome
You must have Google Chrome (or Brave) installed in order for dataframe_image to work. The path to Chrome should automatically be found. If Chrome is not in a standard location, set it with the chrome_path parameter.

Using matplotlib instead of Chrome
If you do not have Chrome installed or cannot get it to work properly, you can alternatively use matplotlib to convert the DataFrames to images. Select this option by setting the table_conversion parameter to 'matplotlib'.

Publish to Medium
Closely related to this package is jupyter_to_medium, which publishes your notebooks directly and quickly as Medium blog posts.

Dependencies
You must have the following Python libraries installed.